# GAE High Replication Datastore in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, entity-framework, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I just want to store some data in the GAE High Replication Datastore.
so I added a Servlet Module and deployed it to my App Engine Project.

How can i store my Data now ?

I tried stuff like this:
{

```
DataStoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDataStoreService();
Entity entity = new Entity("Person",name);
entity.setProperty("name",name);
entity.setproperty("age",age);
datastore.put(entity);
```

}
in the doGet-method of the Servlet and launched it but no Entities showed up in my DatastoreViewer.

Comment: please provide the full servlet code and can you confirm the method is actually being called?

Comment: I did the same thing in eclipse(Web Application Project) and it worked out.
the Entity showed up in my DatastoreViewer, But if i create a Servlet in Android Studio and run it, it isnt working.